# Validation: show radio button when checked and validate

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a form with 2 radio boxes.
On start the 2th radio box has to be hidden. (this i aleady got)
2th radio box only shows when option 1 is NOT checked. (this i aleady got)

The first radio box has to be always required. (this i aleady got)
When the 2th radio box shows, it has to be required. ==> this is the problem.

Here is my code. Hope you guys can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#form").validate({rules: {E1a:{required: true}}});
    $("#radio2").hide();

    $('#radio1').change(function() {
        if ($("#ervaarzichwassen1").is(':checked')) {
                $("#radio2").hide();
        }
        else
        {
                $("#radio2").show();
                jQuery("#form").validate({rules: {E1b:{required: true}}});
        }
    }); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
<h4>Question 1</h4>
    <div id="radio1">
    <input type="radio" id="ervaarzichwassen1" name="E1a" value="1"><label for="ervaarzichwassen1">Verloopt naar wens</label>
    <input type="radio" id="ervaarzichwassen2" name="E1a" value="2"><label for="ervaarzichwassen2">Probleem - niet hinderlijk</label>
    <input type="radio" id="ervaarzichwassen3" name="E1a" value="3"><label for="ervaarzichwassen3">Probleem - hinderlijk voor mij</label>
    <input type="radio" id="ervaarzichwassen4" name="E1a" value="4"><label for="ervaarzichwassen4">Probleem - hinderlijk voor mantelzorger</label>
    <input type="radio" id="ervaarzichwassen5" name="E1a" value="5"><label for="ervaarzichwassen5">Probleem - hinderlijk voor beide</label>
    </div>
<br>
    <div id="radio2">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
    <input type="radio" id="hieraanwerkenzichwassen1" name="E1b" value="1"><label for="hieraanwerkenzichwassen1">Ja</label>
    <input type="radio" id="hieraanwerkenzichwassen2" name="E1b" value="2"><label for="hieraanwerkenzichwassen2">Nee</label>
    </div>
<br>    
<input type="submit" name="volgende" value="Volgende" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default jquery validate ignores the hidden fields, so you could add the required rule for E1b from the beggining.
The way hidden fields are ignored is with the [ignore](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions) option, which by default is the selector `:hidden`.

So you could simply do that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //By default ignore option is set as ":hidden" so all hidden fields are ignored
    jQuery("#form").validate({
        //ignore: ":hidden", This is the default option, no need to set it
        rules: {
            E1a:{required: true},
            E1b:{required: true}
        }
    });

    $("#radio2").hide();
    $('#radio1').change(function() {
        if ($("#ervaarzichwassen1").is(':checked')) {
            $("#radio2").hide();
        } else {
            $("#radio2").show();
        }
    });    
});
```

You can try it [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/os4z7rkz/).

Alternatively, you can use the [`.rules()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules) method to add/remove the required rules from the E1b radio (Although I think the first option is cleaner as you don´t need to add/remove rules):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            E1a:{required: true}
        }
    });
    $("#radio2").hide();

    $('#radio1').change(function() {
        if ($("#ervaarzichwassen1").is(':checked')) {
            $("#radio2").hide();
            $('input[name="E1b"]').rules('remove');
        } else {
            $("#radio2").show();
            $('input[name="E1b"]').rules('add', { required: true });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1j1j91s/) to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use required inside your html tags

```
<input type="radio" id="hieraanwerkenzichwassen1" name="E1b" value="1" required><label for="hieraanwerkenzichwassen1">Ja</label>
```

jQuery

```
$("#radio1").prop('required',true);//or   $("#radio1").addClass("required"); 
$("#radio2").prop('required',true);//or   $("#radio2").addClass("required");
```

**EDIT:**

if that doesn't work you may try [Webshims library](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) (jQuery) which is built on top of Modernizr.

Comment: This does not work on an iPad or older Android tablets.

Comment: Where do I need this Jquery code you have added?
I tried placing it under the change function, but this does not work.

Comment: you can try that just below your `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`